# Is it a good example for local martingale, but not for martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

If $B$ is a Brownian-motion in the $\mathcal{F}$ filtration, then the following process is a good example for being a local martingale, but not a martingale?$$S_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1-s}dB_{s},\;\;\;t\in\left[0,1\right)$$

Comment: Unless mistaken this is a martingale on [0,1), so you should check instead the inverse euclidian norm of the a 3-d Brownian motion for  $t \in\mathbb R^+ $ starting at $(0,0,1)$ which is a classical example.

Comment: I had the same opinion, but I made a simulation, and there as s approached 1, the expected value process started to blowing up, so it hasn't stayed constant as it should has. (The expected value process should has stayed constant, because we considered it as a martingale.) What is the truth then?

Comment: This is a martingale up to time t=1 (1 excluded) as you can see that the quadratic variation of this process at time t is equal to $t/(1-t)$ so it is normal to numerically observe that it is more volatile as it approaches 1 where the quadratic variation blows up to $\infty$. May be you can rescale the process to make this a local martingale (I remind you that the local martingale is defined for t tending to $+\infty$ not 1).